# Tesseract .net on macos, how to reference libdl.dylib on macOS12?

Tags: xcode, macos, tesseract, dylib, libdl

I'm running a .net application that requires a reference to `libdl.so`

```
System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(liblibdl.so, 0x0001): tried: 'liblibdl.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblibdl.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblibdl.so' (no such file), '/Users/Amplicity/Documents/liblibdl.so' (no such file)
```

After some light reading, i found that `libdl.so` is the linux equivalent of `libdl.dylib`, I then tried to find `libdl.dylib` on my machine.

```
➜  lib locate libdl.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libdl.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libdl.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libdl.dylib
```

There are only tvos, watchos, and ios signed `libdl.dylib`'s available. Some more light reading reveals that somewhere around xcode 7, `.dylib` files were replaced with `.tbd`, which is a text file that references dylibs elsewhere.

```
➜  lib locate libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libdl.tbd
```

I attempted to symlink the `.tbd` to the `.so` that my .net application expects, but .net complained that it was net a mach-o file.

I then attempted to symlink the tvos `.dylib` to the `.so`, and got a different error stating that it needed to be signed for macos.

How can I find/conjure `libdl.dylib` on macOS12, so that I may directly reference it in my application?

Comment: You don't need `libdl.dylib`. In the macOS SDK, `libdl.tbd` is a symlink to `libSystem.tbd`, which is always linked, so anything you could need from libdl is already available anyway. That said, your program seems to search for `liblibdl.so`, not `libdl.so`, so either it's looking for a different library, or it's looking, with the wrong name, for a library that is always loaded.

Comment: Thank you! it does look for liblibdl.so, and I can see where it's looking, but that dependency cannot be found anywhere it's looking.  How can I find the location of `liblibdl.so` so I can make sure the application looks in the correct spot?

Comment: `liblibdl` is not a system library, so I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a bit confused -- you said that my program (which is using tesseract, that's where this dependency requirement comes from) should search for `liblibdl.so`, which is included somewhere within the `libSystem.tbd` reference, but there's no way to directly reference the `liblibdl.so` library? Could you elaborate? having a hard time wrapping my head around what i'm dealing with

Comment: No. I'm saying `libdl` and `liblibdl` sounds like two different things. Further, `libdl` is not a thing on macOS because dynamic linking functionality is part of libSystem, but the SDK aliases `libdl` to `libSystem`, likely so that ancient code that tries to link against libdl will compile fine. What `liblibdl` is supposed to be though I have no idea, but it couldn't be part of the OS simply due to the `.so` extension already. So either you're supposed to bring that library yourself, or your code is not compatible with macOS. What does your code actually use the library for?

Comment: Thank you for explaining here. The library that references it is [tesseract](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/588), a tesseract-ocr wrapper for .net. The linked issue is very relevant, although it seems to apply a fix to reference the `.dylib`, which I won't have.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot rebuild that application, `cause currently` libdl.so` would not be requested as it is not deployed anymore as standalone.

Try to make symlink of `libdl.so` to `libc.so` (or whichever version is installed with your .net platform package, `libc.so.x`)

Comment: Thanks for your response here! `libc.so` is expected to be installed with .net? or is this from mac os? How can I find the location of `libc.so.x` ?